# Can asp.net core policies and claims handle resource/activity based authorization?

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I'm looking into asp.net core and the new security policies and claims functionality. Having just looked at it I don't see how it is much better than the existing authorize attribute logic in the past where hard-coded roles or users are decorated on controllers, methods etc.  To me the issues has just been moved from hard-coding in attributes to hard-coding policies.

Ideally I would like to perform activity/resource based authorization where everything would be database driven.  Each activity or resource would be stored in the database and a permission/role would be assigned to the resource.

While researching the topic I found this fantastic article by Stefan Wloch that pretty much covers exactly what I'm looking to do.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1079552/Custom-Roles-Based-Access-Control-RBAC-in-ASP-NE

So my question is with the new core features how does it prevent us from having to hard-code and recompile when the time comes to change what roles/permissions are allowed to access a controller or method in a controller? I understand how claims can be used to store anything but the policy portion seems susceptible to change, which gets us back to square one.  Don't get me wrong, loving asp.net core and all the great changes, just looking for more information on how to handle authorization.

Comment: do you still searching for the answer of this? i might have some idea

Comment: I'm always looking:)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 things that need to be consider in implementing what you want. The first one is how to model the Controller-Action access in database, the second one is to apply that setting in asp.net core Identity.

The first one, there are too many possibilities depend on the application itself, so lets create a Service interface named `IActivityAccessService` that encapsulate. We use that service via dependency injection so that anything that we need can be injected to it.

As for the second one, it can be achieved by customize `AuthorizationHandler` in a policy-based authorization. The first step is to setup things in `Startup.ConfigureServices` :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ActivityAccess", policy => policy.Requirements.Add( new ActivityAccessRequirement() ));
});
services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, ActivityAccessHandler>();
//inject the service also
services.AddScoped<IActivityAccessService, ActivityAccessService>();
//code below will be explained later
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

next we create the `ActivityAccessHandler`:

```
public class ActivityAccessHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ActivityAccessRequirement>
{
    readonly IActivityAccessService _ActivityAccessService;

    public ActivityAccessHandler (IActivityAccessService r)
    {
        _ActivityAccessService = r;
    }

    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authHandlerContext, ActivityAccessRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
        {
            var area = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["area"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var controller = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var action = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string)?.ToLower();
            var id = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"] as string)?.ToLower();
            if (_ActivityAccessService.IsAuthorize(area, controller, action, id))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }               
        }            
    }
}

public class ActivityAccessRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement 
{
    //since we handle the authorization in our service, we can leave this empty
}
```

Since we can use dependency injection in `AuthorizationHandler`, it is here that we inject the `IActivityAccessService`.

Now that we have access to what resource is being requested, we need to know who is requesting it. This can be done by injecting `IHttpContextAccessor`. Thus `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` is added in code above, it is for this reason.

And for the `IActivityAccessService`, you could do something like:

```
public class ActivityAccessService : IActivityAccessService
{
    readonly AppDbContext _context;
    readonly IConfiguration _config;
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;

    public class ActivityAccessService(AppDbContext d, IConfiguration c, IHttpContextAccessor a, UserManager<AppUser> u) 
    {
        _context = d;
        _config = c;
        _accessor = a;
        _userManager = u;
    }

    public bool IsAuthorize(string area, string controller, string action, string id)
    {
        //get the user object from the ClaimPrincipals       
        var appUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_accessor.HttpContext.User);
        //get user roles if necessary
        var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser);
        // all of needed data are available now, do the logic of authorization
        return result;
    } 
}
```

Please note that the code in IsAuthorize body above is an example. While it will works,  people might say it's not a good practice. But since `IActivityAccessService` is just a common simple service class, we can inject anything that wee need to it and modify the `IsAuthorize` method signature in any way that we want to. For example, we can just pass the `filterContext.RouteData` instead.

As for how to apply this to a controller or action:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ActivityAccess")] 
public ActionResult<IActionResult> GetResource(int resourceId)
{
    return Resource;
}
```

hope this helps